# Laravel 5: fresh() on a model doesn't work in PHPUnit

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

What I've been trying is to reload a model in testing.

I've been using `fresh()`, which doesn't work in testing for some reason. (Possibly this is a bug)

Here is a snippet.

```
//There is a relationship between Order and OrderItem.
//One Order hasMany OrderItem

$order    = factory(Order::class)->create([...]);
$orderItem = factory(OrderItem::class)->create([
    'order_id'    => $order->id,
]);
$response = $this->delete('/api/order/' . $order->id);
$response->assertResponseStatus(200);
//This passes.

$orderItem = $orderItem->fresh();
$this->assertEquals($orderItem->some_attribute, 0);
```

The last line results in `trying to get property of non-object`.

I changed
    `$orderItem = $orderItem->fresh();`
into
    `$orderItem->fresh();`

This approach didn't refresh `$orderItem` at all.

Do you see anything I'm doing wrong?

Any advice will be appreciated.

**PS**

```
$orderItem = OrderItem::find($orderItem->id);
```

I tried this approach, which resulted in `trying to get property of non-object` as well.

Comment: code looks okay too. I think it's a bug too. May I know what version are you using?

Comment: Regarding your final note: you are getting a property of non object because the model doesn't exist because the delete call worked.

You should change the final find() to a findOrFail() and then assert a ModelNotFoundException. Get rid of the final ->id.

Comment: @Kenth I'm using 5.1. Maybe you would suggest using the latest version, but now what I'm doing is to maintain an old application developed with 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

`factory()` return the instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory`

it does not have any `fresh()` method implemented in it.

Model has an implementation of `fresh()` method.

```
fresh(array|string $with = []) //Reload a fresh model instance from the database.
```

and

```
OrderItem::find($orderItem->id);
```

returns collection.

Here is what you can do.

```
OrderItem::where('id',  $orderItem->id)->fresh();
```

reference:

https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Factory.html

Hope this helps